# ACR1222 ACOS6 Generate Key returns Invalid INS (6D 00)

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have a working application based on ACR38-SAM (SLE5528) which I'm upgrading into contactless based on ACR1222L (NTAG213)

The problem is that the ACOS6 SAM returns 6D00 every time I call the GenerateKey using the same code I used for the AC38-SAM.

For example: 80 88 00 81 08 - 04 B4 1D 25 B2 17 3C 80

Comment: What made you think that the instruction sets of these very different chips are similar or even identical?

Comment: I'm referring to the ACOS6 which is the exact same card in both devices. are you suggesting that the APDU should be different in each device that connect to the same SAM card?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a problem with the SAM card itself, others works well.